# How to disable OPTIONS, TRACE HTTP methods on ADFS 3.0 Server

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

Our Security team has done an audit on one of the applications and they have raised concerns related to the methods that ADFS 3.0 server has raised.

They want us to disable HTTP methods **OPTIONS, TRACE** and to enable **X-XSS-Protection** header. I have went through the different powershell commands that ADFS exposes to configure the server. I couldn't find anything using which I can control these headers.

Did anyone come across this and If so, how did you solve it?

The other option I have is to check with the Network team and see if they can add some rules to the Load Balancer/Reverse Proxy. But I don't want to go that far, especially if I can just configure it on the ADFS box itself.

Comment: Have to look at it but I usually use the rp for security,  SSL striping, and small http adjustments trafic between rp and any webinstance is left unsecured on a dedicated vlan, firewalls are figured to only accept http requests from rp.

Answer (score 1):

We have been able to successfully implement this using the reverse proxy (BIG IP F5).

All the reverse proxy needed is the SSL cert and private key to decrypt and look at if the message HTTP verb is OPTIONS/ TRACE.

Answer (score 0):

This level of configuration on ADFS does not exist because of security. Basically it's a black box.

You would have to do this via proxy or LB.